# setLineWidth works differently on different test machines

Tags: opengl-es, width, line, andengine, bezier

I make a game in which I draw bezier curve like this:

```
    final VertexBufferObjectManager vbom = engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
    final HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject pMeshVBOM = new HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject(vbom, pBufferData, pBufferData.length, DrawType.DYNAMIC, true, Mesh.VERTEXBUFFEROBJECTATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);
    final HighPerformanceLineChainVertexBufferObject pLeftCurbLineChainVBOM = new HighPerformanceLineChainVertexBufferObject(vbom, triangleCount * 3, DrawType.DYNAMIC, true, leftCurb.VERTEXBUFFEROBJECTATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);
    final HighPerformanceLineChainVertexBufferObject pRightCurbLineChainVBOM = new HighPerformanceLineChainVertexBufferObject(vbom, triangleCount * 3, DrawType.DYNAMIC, true, rightCurb.VERTEXBUFFEROBJECTATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);

    leftCurb = new LineStrip(0, 0, 10f, triangleCount, pLeftCurbLineChainVBOM){

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            drawByBezier(curveOffset);

        };

        void drawByBezier(float curveOffset){

            for (int triangleIndex = 0; triangleIndex < triangleCount; triangleIndex++) {

                this.setX(triangleIndex, getBezierX(triangleIndex, -curveBottom, -curveControlPoint, -curveTop + curveOffset));
                this.setY(triangleIndex, triangleIndex * heightIncrement);

            }
        }
```

By changing a value of curveOffset I change the look of the curve.

The first parameter (10f) is a line width. When I test it on Galaxy S5 (android 5) the line width is drawn as about 2 pixels wide and if I put lower value there, like 1.5f the drawn line is very thin. On the other hand putting large numbers like 100f doesn't do anything - line stays at same (small) width. 
I tested this on Galaxy S3 mini (android 4.1.2) and the line width works there (performance is other thing though...). Line is drawn as I wanted to. How can I do that in GalaxyS5 (android 5). For me it looks like device or OS specific problem (openGL version?), but is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES implementations do not have to support drawing of wide lines. You can query the range of available line widths with:

```
float[] range = new float[2];
GLES20.glGetFloatv(GLES20.GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, range, 0);
// range[0] is the minimum supported line width.
// range[1] is the maximum supported line width.
```

This gives you the range supported by the specific device you're running on. Compliant implementations can have a maximum as low as 1.0. This means that you cannot use wide lines if you want your code to run on all devices.

If you want something that has the appearance of wide lines, and will work on any device, you have to draw polygons. You can draw something that looks like a line as a thin quad that is oriented towards the viewer.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Thanks